# Conexion a base de datos funciona, pero no logro ingresar

Tags: mysqli

**Tengo el siguiente problema con mi sistema:**

> *Conecta a la base de datos, pero no entra al sistema. la consulta de usuario devuelve usuario incorrecto a pesar de mostrar los mismos
>   resultados que la base de datos.*

**Conexion.php**

```
<?php
$file = 'config.ini.php';
$config = parse_ini_file($file, true);
$host = $config['database']['host'];
$user = $config['database']['username'];
$pass = $config['database']['password'];
$schema = $config['database']['schema'];
$encode = $config['database']['encode'];
class conexion extends mysqli

    {
    public

    function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $schema)
        {
        parent::__construct($host, $user, $pass, $schema);
        if (mysqli_connect_error())
            {
            printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            }else
            {
            echo "conexión exitosa";
            }
        }
    }

$conexion = new conexion($host, $user, $pass, $schema);

mysqli_set_charset( $conexion, $encode);
?>
```

**Conectarse.php**

```
    <?php
session_start();
/* Verifico que CONECTAR tenga un valor, esto para validar que este activo javascript y que no entraron por ruta forzada */
$conectar =1;

if ($conectar == 1)
    {
    include '__conexion.php';

    include_once 'funciones/passwordLib.php';

    $usuario = $_POST['txtusuario'] ? : '';
    echo "<br>"."usuario ingresado:".$usuario."<br>";
    $contrasena = $_POST['txtcontrasena'] ? : '';
    echo "<br>"."Contraseña ingresada:".$contrasena."<br>";
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT hash,nivel_id,unidad_id FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? LIMIT 1");
    echo "var_dump de statement"."<br>";
  var_dump($statement);
    $statement->bind_param('s', $usuario);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    if ($statement->num_rows === 0)
        {
        $statement->close();
        /* Si no existe el usuario en la BBDD le decimos que algo esta incorrecto */
        echo ('<script>alert("Usuario o contrase\u00f1a incorrecto, vuelva a ingresar");</script>');
       /* echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");*/
        exit;
        }
      else
        {
        $statement->bind_result($contrasena_BD, $nivel_id, $unidad_id);
        echo "Contraseña en la base de datos: <br>".$contrasena_BD;
        echo "Nivel de acceso <br>".$nivel_id;
        echo "Unidad del usuario <br>".$unidad_id;
        while ($statement->fetch())
            {
            if (password_verify($_POST['txtcontrasena'], $contrasena_BD))
                {
                $_SESSION['nivel'] = $nivel_id;
                $_SESSION['conectado'] = true; //esta conectado//
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
                $_SESSION['unidad'] = $unidad_id;
                $_SESSION['inicio'] = time();
                $_SESSION['expira'] = $_SESSION['inicio'] + (10 * 60); //TIEMPO DE SESIÃƒâ€œN//
                if ($nivel_id == 0)
                    {
                    /* Mensaje de bienvenida segun la clase */
                    echo ('<script>alert("Bienvenido al Sistema Automatizado de OMD");</script>');
                  /*  echo ("<script>window.location = 'menu_unidades.php';</script>");*/
                    }
                elseif ($nivel_id == 1)
                    {
                    echo ('<script>alert("Bienvenido al Sistema Automatizado de OMD");</script>');
                   /*   echo ("<script>window.location = 'menu_administradores.php';</script>");         */
                    }
                elseif ($nivel_id > 1)
                    {
                    echo ('<script>alert("Este usuario no corresponde al sistema");</script>');
                  /* echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");*/
                    }
                }
              else
                {
                /* Mensaje cuando la contraseÃƒÂ±a no coincide */
                echo ('<script>alert("Usuario o contrase\u00f1a incorrecto, vuelva a ingresar");</script>');
                /*echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");*/
                }
            }

        $statement->close();
        }
    }
  else
    {
    /* Mensaje cuando quieren entrar por ruta forzada */
    echo ('<script>alert("No tiene permisos suficientes para acceder a esta parte del sistema");</script>');
   /* echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");*/
    }

?>
```

**Resultados de conectarse.php**

```
   usuario ingresado:e1_1dinf
  Contraseña ingresada:personalz1
var_dump de statement
object(mysqli_stmt)[2]
  public 'affected_rows' => null
  public 'insert_id' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'param_count' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'errno' => null
  public 'error' => null
  public 'error_list' => null
  public 'sqlstate' => null
  public 'id' => null
Contraseña en la base de datos: 
$2y$10$GUv4G8lxvy6eJ9q93UFyFuU8vqbOz1I9w2wvb48vnZZmtBoklrBK6Nivel de acceso 
0Unidad del usuario 
033100000000
```

> **EJEMPLO DE CODIGO MINIMO**:

**Index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="index" name="index" method="POST" action="conectarse.php">
    <input type="text" size="25" maxlength="50" name="txtusuario" id="txtusuario">
    <input type="password" size="25" maxlength="20" name="txtcontrasena" id="txtcontrasena">
    <input type="submit" name="entrar" id="entrar" value="Entrar" onclick="validarLOGIN();">
    </body>
    </form>
    </html>
```

**Conectarse.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
    include '__conexion.php';
    include_once 'funciones/passwordLib.php';
    $usuario = $_POST['txtusuario'] ? : '';
    $contrasena = $_POST['txtcontrasena'] ? : '';
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT hash,nivel_id,unidad_id FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bind_param('s', $usuario);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    $statement->bind_result($contrasena_BD, $nivel_id, $unidad_id);
    while ($statement->fetch())
            {
            if (password_verify($_POST['txtcontrasena'], $contrasena_BD))
                {
                $_SESSION['nivel'] = $nivel_id;
                $_SESSION['conectado'] = true; 
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
                $_SESSION['unidad'] = $unidad_id;
                $_SESSION['inicio'] = time();
                $_SESSION['expira'] = $_SESSION['inicio'] + (10 * 60);
                }
              else
                {
         echo "Usuario Incorrecto";
                              }
            }

        $statement->close();

    }
?>
```

El sistema deberia luego pasarte a tu menu, pero muestra las contraseñas como incorrectas, al parecer podria ser error de **password_verify**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pregunta viene de otra pregunta que ha sido objeto de varios comentarios. El problema, como muchas veces es el punto de partida, el enfoque que se da al uso de las conexiones a la base de datos y luego, en consecuencia, a la manera de consultarla.

Trataré de responder a la pregunta, aunque reconozco que MySQLi no me gusta por varios motivos ya expuestos en otras respuestas y el problema presentado aquí me lo confirma. Pero bueno, veo que la gente insiste en usar MySQLi en vez de PDO, o será que MySQLi da demasiados problemas y por eso vemos pocas preguntas relativas a PDO. Puede ser.

Bueno, hagamos un esfuerzo por responder **en general**. Pero para no complicarnos, pasa al punto 3.

### 1º Trata bien a tu conexión

Para ello lo mejor es una clase dedicada a la conexión a la base de datos.

Ejemplo sencillo de una clase usando MySQLi:

Modificar los valores tales como host, user, etc.

```
<?php

class SQLiDb  {
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $user = 'root';
    private $pass = '';
    private $db = 'example';
    private $myconn;

    function connect() {
        $con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
        if (!$con) {
             //die('Imposible conectar'); //die no me gusta, lo siento
              return NULL;
        } else {
            $this->myconn = $con;
            echo 'Conexión exitosa!';}
        return $this->myconn;
    }

    function close() {
        mysqli_close($myconn);
        echo 'Conexión cerrada';
    }

}
```

### 2º Usando la conexión en cualquier parte

Lo bueno de tener nuestra clase de conexión es que podemos usarla en cualquier parte. Como se trata de una clase, usemos el estilo POO, creando el objeto con `new`.

```
include_once ("tu-arcivo-de-conexion.php");
$db=new SQLiDb();

// Para verificar si hay conexión no hay que hacer nada más que esto    
if ($db)
{    
//Código con la bd    
}else{
echo "No ha sido posible la conexión";
}
```

### 3º Pasemos al caso concreto que nos ocupa

Los puntos 1 y 2 son para ilustrar una forma más o menos organizada de usar las conexiones.

Para intentar dar una solución a tu problema, hagamos esto:

Asumimos que la conexión funciona y que obtienes resultados de la siguiente manera:

```
//Usemos variables para un código menos confuso
$usuario = $_POST['txtusuario'] ? : '';
$sql = "SELECT hash,nivel_id,unidad_id FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? LIMIT 1";
$statement->bind_param('s', $usuario);
$statement->execute();
$statement->store_result();

//Olvidemos por ahora el dichoso num_rows

while($data = mi_fetchassoc($statement))
{ 

/*
 * Había olvidado esto
*/
        $contrasena_BD=$data["hash"];
        $nivel_id=$data["nivel_id"];
        $unidad_id =$data["unidad_id"];
/*
 * ***********************************************
*/

        if (password_verify($_POST['txtcontrasena'], $contrasena_BD))
        {
            //Todo el código que haga falta
            $_SESSION['nivel'] = $nivel_id;
            $_SESSION['conectado'] = true; 
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
            $_SESSION['unidad'] = $unidad_id;
            $_SESSION['inicio'] = time();
            $_SESSION['expira'] = $_SESSION['inicio'] + (10 * 60);
         }
          else
         {
           echo "Usuario Incorrecto";
         }
}

//Esto lo usabas mal y lo hacías dentro del while
$statement->free();

//Cerramos la conexión
$conexion->close();

/*
    * Una función personalizada
    * para obtener un arreglo asociativo del resultado
    * Esta misma función nos sirve para saber si hubo resultados
    * Pues devuelve NULL si no hay datos y podemos evaluarla
    * en cualquier parte del código usando algo como
    * if mi_fetchassoc($statement){hay datos}else{no hay datos}
*/  

function mi_fetchassoc($stmt)
{
    if($stmt->num_rows>0)
    {
        $rs = array();
        $md = $stmt->result_metadata();
        $params = array();
        while($field = $md->fetch_field()) {
            $params[] = &$rs[$field->name];
        }
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
        if($stmt->fetch())
            return $rs;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: @A.Cedadno me funciona, mira como lo puse: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0B3RAN

Comment: A ver @Victor-Random:  Deja tu conexión como la tenías, ya que has dicho que funcionaba, solamente haz los cambios indicados en el punto 3º. He puesto los otros puntos para mostrar más o menos una forma de usar la conexión.

Comment: ya cambie a la conexion vieja, me da error el es archivo de conectar del paso nro 3 http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0B4455

Comment: Deja tus include como los tenías: `include '__conexion.php';
    include_once 'funciones/passwordLib.php';`, te dije que lo indicado en 1º y en 2º era explicativo.

Comment: listo, por cierto te paso el link de la libreria de hasheo: https://github.com/Antnee/phpPasswordHashingLib

Error. http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0B49W0

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57480/discussion-between-victor-random-and-a-cedano).